# TableView reload issue

Tags: iphone, uitableview, sdk

Each cell of my TableView contains UIImage, I made an action to change all images in UIImage in each cell, then reload the table.
The images didn't change until I scroll the table.
I know the TableView is loading cell during scrolling.
But is there a way to fix my issue?

Thanks

Comment: maybe u can post your code here.. and i need to know whether u use lazy loading image, or the default one..

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are calling `reloadData` or `beingUpdates`/`endUpdates` from the MainThread.  You can check this via:

```
if (![NSThread mainThread]) {
    return;
}
```

Here is an example. The ViewController is a delegate of an ImageDownloader, and when the image is done downloading it called -acceptImage, which then performs a selector on the main thread to do the table updates.  Also, see the [UITableView Reference](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=8&ved=0CD8QFjAH&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2FIOS%2Fdocumentation%2FUIKit%2FReference%2FUITableView_Class%2FReference%2FReference.html&ei=Q0BpTsexOJSBsgLvzeGLDg&usg=AFQjCNFcTY0QlLcVnAYzWLD949_NMjc5_w&sig2=2F-GgSGwLlzkhgkoM-k_QQ)

```
- (void)setDownloadedImage:(NSMutableDictionary *)d {
    UIImageView *imgV = (UIImageView *)[d objectForKey:@"imageView"];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [d objectForKey:@"userInfo"];
    [thumbs addObject:[ImageWorks imageWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[d objectForKey:@"image"]] scaledToSize:imgV.frame.size]];
    [table beginUpdates];
    [table insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle];
    [table endUpdates];
    loadingView.hidden = YES;
}

- (void)acceptImage:(NSData *)image ForUserInfo:(id)userInfo ForUrl:(NSString *)url {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSMutableDictionary *d = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    iPhoneMyTableCell *cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"iPhoneMyTableCell" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
    [d setObject:userInfo forKey:@"userInfo"];
    [d setObject:(image ? image : UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"ImageMissing.png"])) forKey:@"image"];
    [d setObject:cell.myImageView forKey:@"imageView"];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setDownloadedImage:) withObject:d waitUntilDone:YES];
    [d release];
    [pool drain];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you call `[tableView reloadData];`?